# Clarification needed about odd double assignment syntax in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code:

```
var $scope, modelValue;
modelValue = $scope.model = {};
```

Can anyone please explain what this double assignment mean in javascript?

Why does one need the second assignment?

Comment: Why ? to save you from writing it twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line `modelValue = $scope.model = {};` is exactly like writing this:

```
$scope.model = {};
modelValue = $scope.model;
```

When writing an expression: `variable = expression`, the expression is evaluated before the assignment, so this statement is evaluated from right to left:

`variable = (variable = expression) // inner expression`

I found this docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w2h1k9x(v=vs.94).aspx:

> The = operator behaves like other operators, so expressions that contain it have a value. This means that you can chain assignment operators as follows: j = k = l = 0. In this case j, k, and l equal zero.

Comment: Interesting... Can you please confirm that the `$scope.model = {};` instruction is  evaluated first?

Answer (score 1):

With this statement you have a direct reference to the empty object via `modelValue` and set the model under the `$scope` namespace/object to the same object. If you need to dereference to the model it should be quicker via the direct reference. And to shorten things up (referencing the same object with two variables) you make a double assignment.